# how to get these tables of bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap, does anyone know how to get the below picture's html code?

What is the name of these three tables? My client send me this picture, and they want these tables.

I don't know where I get and what the name of this is!

[image]

Comment: It would be far easier if you asked your client to send the HTML file instead.

Comment: Just the upper one is a table.  The other two are charts. You could use Chart.js or another js library for that.

Comment: i google last 3 hours :( but no success